# UIView rotation doesn't work properly in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, device-orientation

My `UIView`should always be in fullscreen but that doesn't really work sometimes. Every time the user rotates the device, the method `viewWillLayoutSubviews` gets called.
Here I print the height and width of the UIView.
The height and width of the UIView are right (1024 width,768 height in landscape mode).
Anyway, on the iPad the View hasn't this size altough I write it to the Console.
In portrait mode everything works, but in landscape not so what could be the problem?
If the iPad is in landscape mode and I start the app it works but if I rotate it (then it's portrait) and rotate it back to landscape, the view isn't in fullscreen anymore.

Comment: are you doing any custom layout apart from the interface builder, are all your constraints properly set up?

Comment: I hope that they are right. The App is a Camera and taking photos works perfectly. The problem is when I take a video the rotation doesn't work properly although I did it the same way as for taking the photo

Comment: Sounds like your constraints aren't properly set up.

Comment: But I just have a UIView and every time the user rotates the device, i set `myView.frame = view.bounds` and so it should be in fullscreen, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply pin the edges of your UIView to the edges of the view controller's main view with `constant` of 0, once when you add the UIView to the interface, and all will be well thereafter.

Comment: Ok, the constraints are the problem but I set some programmatically and if I set the recommended constraints, the one I set programmatically don't work properly

Comment: @mafioso But isn't that just a problem of not knowing how to apply constraints properly? It's very simple but you have to know the rules. I've no idea what you are doing with constraints at this point, and you didn't describe it at all, so I can't help further. But I do believe that having exactly and only the four constraints I described in my answer is the right solution to your problem.